# Replace matching HTML tag with Regexp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

[EDIT] **First of all:** I am aware that by DOM manipulation tools you can easily modify DOM structures. (These are available in every browser and even in Node by third party libraries.)

**The goal of his question** is if someone can come up with a clever idea if this problem can be solved by Regexp in JavaScript without DOM.

Thank you![End of EDIT]

Let's say I have the following **HTML snippet** *as a string*:

```
<p>
    <div class="something">
        <span>
            <div class="else">My precious text.</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</p>
```

I wish to get rid of the `<div class="something">` tags with **RegExp** in order to get something like this (indentation does not matter):

```
<p>
    <span>
        <div class="else">My precious text.</div>
    </span>
</p>
```

So, my attempt was:

```
htmlString.replace(/<div class="something">([\s\S]+?)<\/div>/gi, "$1");
```

But it will match for the closing tag of `<div class="else">` of course.

How can I do it properly using **just vanilla JS** and by **not using** *the DOM manipulation tools* of the browser? (i.e. in Node)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/8284239

Comment: There's no way to do it "properly" using just vanilla JS. Use something like [node-jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom).

Comment: Well, if I wanted to use a third party library in Node to emulate DOM, I would recommend [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). However I was just curious if there is someone who is clever enough to solve the above mentioned problem with regexp without third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't the best option for this. You're better off using the querying abilities of JS if it's HTML you're dealing with, here's a quick example of what you could do (oversimplified for explanation purposes):

```
var htmlString = '<p><div class="something"><span><div class="else">My precious text.</div></span></div></p>';

//Create a DOM element so you can query what you need and manipulate it
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = htmlString;

//Find what you need to remove
var toRemove = newElement.getElementsByClassName("something")[0];
//Grab what you need to keep
var toKeep = toRemove.firstChild;

//Remove the unwanted element
newElement.removeChild(toRemove);

//Append the old child
newElement.appendChild(toKeep);

//If you really want it back as a string
newElement.outerHTML;
```

PS: It's not valid to have a div inside a paragraph element, so you're going to get unpredictable results.

Comment: Using the DOM manipulation tools of the browser this problem is piece of cake, just like you described. However what if I have to solve this without DOM support (i.e. in Node). Just like I commented above, I can use a third party library like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), but I was just curious if someone is clever enough to solve this problem with regexp and without the DOM support or third party library. (PS: I know that I am not supposed to put a `<div>` inside a `<span>`, just used it for the sake of the example.)